# Dynamically add td and tr onclick HTML JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with a row and two TDs

```
<table id="tbTest">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I also have a button that adds a new row with a td dynamically. If the second time is clicked I want to add a second td. if the third time is clicked I want to add a new tr with one td...etc

jquery on click

```
var counter = 2;

if ((counter % 2) == 0) {
    row = $('<tr><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>');
}
else {
    //???????????????
}
row.appendTo('#tbTest');
counter++;
```

I can add a tr and td (first time clicked) but the second time clicked how do I insert a second td in a tr... suggestions?

thanks,

Comment: I would just count how many `td`s are in the last row. If there are already two, add a new row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question, I guess what you want to achieve is to add a new row with table data when the button is first clicked and every other odd time (third time, fifth time etc) and to add a new table data to the created row when the button is clicked a second time and every other even time (fourth time, sixth time etc)

```
var counter = 0,
    row;

$('button').click(function() {
  counter++; //increase value of counter

//for every odd time click
if (counter % 2 != 0) {
    row = $('<tr><td><input type="text"></td></tr>'); //create row
    $('#tbTest').append(row);
}
else {
    //create a table data
    var tableData = $('<td><input type="text"></td>');
    row.append(tableData); //append the table data to the last created row
}
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/976PT/

Comment: Works. Thank you. I understand "$('#tbTest').append(row);" adds row to a table. confused with: "row.append(tableData);" appends a tableData to a row where row is a variable? how does it know to append to a row?

Comment: The variable 'row' is a reference to the created jQuery object that contains the row. 'row.append(tableData)' just appends a table data to the created row stored at variable 'row'. I hope this helps. Pls, up vote my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
var container = $('#tbTest tr:last');
if(container.find('td').length > 1)
{
    $('#tbTest').append('<tr></tr>');
     container = $('#tbTest tr:last');
}
$(container).append('<td><input type="text"/></td>');
```

I'm not sure if this code is 100% correct, but basically you need to check if the last `tr` element contains more than one `td`, and if it does, create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var i = 0;
    $("button").click(function () {
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
            row = $('<td><input type="text"/></td>');
            row.appendTo('#tbTest tr:last-child');
        } else {
            row = $('<tr><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>');
            row.appendTo('#tbTest');
        }
        i++
    })
})
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aK73x/5/